# NullPointerException sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to store OAuth tokens in a database using sqlite. When I am creating a new row, I am getting "NullPointerException." I am receiving the token from Instagram (it works if I am storing it in shared prefs), but fails if I try and store it in sqlite.

My TokenDataSource:

```
public class TokenDataSource 
{
      // Database fields
      private SQLiteDatabase database;
      private DBHelper dbHelper;
      private String[] allColumns = { DBHelper.COLUMN_ID,
          DBHelper.COLUMN_TOKEN };

      public void close(){ 
          dbHelper.close();
      }

      public void open() throws SQLException{ 
          database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      }

      public TokenDataSource(Context context){ 
          dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
      }

      public void deleteInstagramToken(InstagramToken token)
      {
          long id = token.getId();
          database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_INSTA_TOKENS, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID
                    + " = " + id, null);
      }

      public InstagramToken createInstagramToken(String token) 
      {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_TOKEN, token);
            long insertId = database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_INSTA_TOKENS, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_INSTA_TOKENS,
                allColumns, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            InstagramToken newToken = cursorToToken(cursor);
            cursor.close();

            return newToken;
      }

      public List<InstagramToken> getAllInstagramTokens()
      {
          List<InstagramToken> tokens = new ArrayList<InstagramToken>(); 
          Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_INSTA_TOKENS,
                    allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
          cursor.moveToFirst();

          while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
          {
              InstagramToken token = cursorToToken(cursor);
              tokens.add(token);
              cursor.moveToNext();
          }

          cursor.close();

          return tokens;
      }

      private InstagramToken cursorToToken(Cursor cursor)
      {
          InstagramToken token = new InstagramToken(); 
          token.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
          token.setToken(cursor.getString(1));

          return token;
      }
}
```

My DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
      public static final String TABLE_INSTA_TOKENS = "insta_tokens";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_TOKEN = "token";

      private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "status.db";
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

      // Database creation sql statement
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
          + TABLE_INSTA_TOKENS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_TOKEN
          + " text not null);";

      public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INSTA_TOKENS);
        onCreate(db);
      }
}
```

The storeAccessToken method:

```
public InstagramSession(Context context) 
{
    this.mCtx = context;
    sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPref.edit();
}

public void storeAccessToken(String accessToken, String id, String username, String name) 
{
    TokenDataSource datasource = new TokenDataSource(mCtx);

    editor.putString(API_ID, id);
    editor.putString(API_NAME, name);
    editor.putString(API_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
    editor.putString(API_USERNAME, username);
    editor.commit();

    datasource.createInstagramToken(accessToken);
}
```

Comment: where do you get the exception?

Comment: You need to call `datasource.open()` before you call `datasource.createInstagramToken(accessToken)` as otherwise your `database` object is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of have a method that stores in member class the instance of your SQLiteDatabase you should call `dbHelper.getWritableDatabase()` every time you need to access it